# RedGate ReadyRoll MySQL support?

Tags: database, redgate, readyroll

Does RedGate ReadyRoll support MySQL databases? Can anyone provide a list of supported databases? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReadyRoll only supports SQL Server for the time being.

Redgate does offer[Schema and Data comparison tools](http://www.red-gate.com/products/mysql/mysql-comparison-bundle/) for MySQL, which will help you manage your database deployments.

Should we see increased demand we may consider MySQL support in future. In the meantime please post this request on our [Uservoice page](https://readyroll.uservoice.com/forums/204125-readyroll-product-feedback).